# Accessing a function define within a function from outside

Tags: javascript, html, javascript-objects

I have some code whose structure I cannot change. And functions defined in such a manner.

```
var Something.someFunc = function(e){
    function funcTwo(){

    }
    ...
    ...
    ...
    ...
}
```

I need to call funcTwo from outside of this structure. How do I go about doing it ? Someone suggested that i would have to use the".prototype" property but I cannot get this to work.

Anyone have a suitable solution, as i cannot change the structure of the code.

Comment: You cannot without changing the code inside `Something.someFunc` And what is someFunc? Are you creating objects with `new Somthing.someFunc()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`funcTwo` is defined in `someFunc` scope. There is now way for you to get access to it unless you can somehow modify the code.

Comment: Thats what I had thought initially, but a friend told me i could using the prototype property. Thanks for confirming that this cannot be done.